# Why does windows give an sqlite3.OperationalError and linux does not?

Tags: python, windows, linux, sqlite

## The problem

I've got a programm that uses [storm 0.14](http://storm.canonical.com) and it gives me this error on windows:

```
sqlite3.OperationError: database table is locked
```

The thing is, under linux it works correctly.

I've got the impression that it happens only after a certain amount of changes have been done, as it happens in some code, that copies a lot of objects.

Turning on the debug mode gives me this on windows:

```
83 EXECUTE: 'UPDATE regularorder_product SET discount=? WHERE regularorder_product.order_id = ? AND regularorder_product.product_id = ?', (Decimal("25.00"), 788, 274)
84 DONE
85 EXECUTE: 'UPDATE repeated_orders SET nextDate=? WHERE repeated_orders.id = ?', (datetime.date(2009, 3, 31), 189)
86 ERROR: database table is locked
```

On linux:

```
83 EXECUTE: 'UPDATE regularorder_product SET discount=? WHERE regularorder_product.order_id = ? AND regularorder_product.product_id = ?', (Decimal("25.00"), 789, 274)
84 DONE
85 EXECUTE: 'UPDATE repeated_orders SET nextDate=? WHERE repeated_orders.id = ?', (datetime.date(2009, 3, 31), 189)
86 DONE
```

## System info

*Windows*

- Windows XP SP 3
- Python 2.5.4
- NTFS partition

*Linux*

- Ubuntu 8.10
- Python 2.5.2
- ext3 partition

## Some code

```
def createRegularOrderCopy(self):
    newOrder = RegularOrder()
    newOrder.date = self.nextDate
    # the exception is thrown on the next line,
    # while calling self.products.__iter__
    # this happens when this function is invoked the second time
    for product in self.products:
        newOrder.customer = self.customer
        newOrder.products.add(product)
        return newOrder

orders = getRepeatedOrders(date)
week = timedelta(days=7)

for order in orders:
    newOrder = order.createRegularOrderCopy()
    store.add(newOrder)
    order.nextDate = date + week
```

## The question

Is there anything about sqlite3/python that differs between windows and linux? What could be the reason for this bug and how can I fix it?

## Another observation

When adding a `COMMIT` at the place where the error happens, this error is thrown instead: `sqlite3.OperationalError: cannot commit transaction - SQL statements in progress`

## Answers to answers

I'm not using multiple threads / processes, therefore concurrency shouldn't be a problem and also I've got only one Store object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem at the moment by replacing the sqlite3-dll with the newest version. I'm still not sure if this was a bug in the windows code of sqlite or if python installed an older version on windows than on linux.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can check the sqlite version by 'import sqlite3', 'print sqlite3.sqlite_version'.  If you put back the original sqlite3.dll, you'll be able to compare.

Comment: Linux: 3.5.9, Windows: 3.4.4, quite a difference.

Answer (score 1):

The "database table is locked" error is often a generic/default error in SQLite, so narrowing down your problem is not obvious.

Are you able to execute *any* SQL queries? I would start there, and get some basic SELECT statements working.  It could just be a permissions issue.

Comment: Yes, 40 statements before it work perfectly. (The last one is included in the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without a little more info on the structure of your database access (which is a little obscured by using Storm).

*I'd start by reading these documents; they contain very relevant information:*

1. https://storm.canonical.com/Manual#SQLite%20and%20threads
2. http://sqlite.org/lockingv3.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you running any sort of anti-virus scanners? Anti-virus scanners will frequently lock a file after it has been updated, so that they can inspect it without it being changed. This may explain why you get this error after a lot of changes have been made; the anti-virus scanner has more new data to scan.

If you are running an anti-virus scanner, try turning it off and see if you can reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like storm is broken, though my first guess was virus scanner as Brian suggested.

Have you tried using `sqlite3_busy_timeout()` to set the timeout very high? This might cause `SQLite3` to wait long enough for the lock holder, whoever that is, to release the lock.

Comment: Is 5 seconds high enough? I'm using the "python" version of storm, so there shoulnd't be a difference between windows and linux. I'm currently investigating if there are different versions of sqlite installed.