# "Database is locked" error in SQLite over a Mac network

Tags: sqlite, file-locking

I have created a simple database using SQLite (actually PySQLite). It works fine when I'm querying or writing to the database from the local machine (ie program and database file on the windows machine drive). However when I copy the database file to my network drive (a time capsule), then Windows machines, although they can see the files and have full read/write access to the drive, give me a "SQL Error: database is locked" even when performing a simple select!

Queries work fine over the network from Macs.

There is no fancy multi-access going on - only one machine has the database open. Seems like some weird Mac networking issue. Happens in either the Python program, or in the SQLite3 command line. I am using SQLite 3.6.14.2.

Anybody seen this problem? Any way of fixing it? Don't really want to get heavy with MYSQL because this is a simple single-user program, but i'd like to use it from multiple machines.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if it can be done on MAC, on Debian I have to mount the samba directory with the **nobrl** option.

From mount.cifs(8):

```
  nobrl
      Do not send byte range lock requests to the server. This is
      necessary for certain applications that break with cifs
      style mandatory byte range locks (and most cifs servers do
      not yet support requesting advisory byte range locks).
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the sqlite FAQ: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5

> "People who have a lot of experience
>   with Windows tell me that file locking
>   of network files is very buggy and is
>   not dependable. If what they say is
>   true, sharing an SQLite database
>   between two or more Windows machines
>   might cause unexpected problems."

So it doesn't work on Windows, it doesn't tell about MAC.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly it fails to lock the file over the network, I think you use SMB protocol so the bugginess comes with the package. If you would like to use SQLite over the network see [SQLite Network](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteNetwork) for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

[I've had a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679162/why-does-windows-give-an-sqlite3-operationalerror-and-linux-does-not/680390#680390) and I solved it by installing a newer sqlite version. Since Python 2.6 the problem has disappeared too because it uses a newer sqlite dll.

Comment: Wish that were so. Sadly I am running the very latest version of SQLite. Basically, looks like SQLite won't work when a windows client queries a file on a mac-based network (in my case Time Capsule). Going to play with other permutations such as running the database on a windows or other *Nix based machine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Carlos. Cherrytree depends on SQLite, and for some reason it recently stopped working with my samba-mounted SQLite database file, complaining about a locked database.  Adding "nobrl" to my ubuntu fstab entry solved the problem.

//192.168.3.122/Files /mnt/Files cifs username=public,password=asdf,rw,noperm,nobrl 0 0

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment: You might not have yet enough rep to comment on others' posts, however something to keep in mind for the future.